# Razor syntax to complete an MVC form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post

I'm very new to using Razor with C# and am conducting this project in order to try to better my understanding of it.

This application is supposed to, once completed, is ask the user to input three integers and then print out the sum of those integers. Right now, I have the basic frame of the View and Controller set up. (There is currently no Model.) The controller is set up to use an HTTP-Post protocol in order to send information to the HTML form.

What I'm struggling with, is the code needed to communicate the data directly to the form, as well as whatever parameters are needed so that ASP.net will ignore the presence of two identically-named controller actions (which I'm told it should be able to do once the Razor syntax is set up properly).

Any guidance here would be very helpful. (Note: It is a requirement that I use the HTTP Post protocol in the finished solution.)

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int firstInt = 0, int secondInt = 0, int thirdInt = 0)
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int firstInt = 0, int secondInt = 0, int thirdInt = 0)
    {
        int sum = firstInt + secondInt + thirdInt;
        ViewBag.result = sum;
    }
```

Index View:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Enter the 1st Number: <input id="firstInt" name="firstInt" type="text" value="0" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter the 2nd Number: <input id="secondInt" name="secondInt" type="text" value="0" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter the 3rd Number: <input id="thirdInt" name="thirdInt" type="text" value="0" /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" /><input id="Reset" type="reset" value="reset" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sum =  @ViewBag.result</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally what you do for Razor views is declare the Model, and use the Razor methods to output the form and form elements.  As Shyju says, you need unique signatures on the actions.

```
@using MyModelNamespace
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HomeController", routevalues, etc..) {
     Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstInt);
}
```

Your post action should take the model as a parameter

```
public ActionResult Index() {
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel m) {
    int sum = m.firstInt + m.secondInt + m.thirdInt;
    ViewBag.result = sum;
    return View(m);
}
```

You can set ViewBag state in your action.

Comment: I've tried something similar before with the declaring the model in the view. I always get the same error though, the program doesn't recognize my Model name.

Comment: you need the right @using statement at the top of the view.  Edited to include.

Comment: I had forgotten to put the @ sign before the using.  Or do you mean that the form is rendering but not routing to the right action on submit?

Comment: Ignore my last two comments. I was able to get the entire thing working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your methods with same name has unique signature. Since you mentioned the user enter the numbers via the form, there is no reason to have those params in the GET action method. Just remove it and it should work now.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Also you need a `return View();` statement in your HttpPost action. Otherwise you will get a compilation error.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int firstInt = 0, int secondInt = 0, int thirdInt = 0)
{
    int sum = firstInt + secondInt + thirdInt;
    ViewBag.result = sum;
    return View();
}
```

If you are going to have many parameter values coming from the form, i would advise creating a view model which has those properties and use that as the parameter.

Comment: Also, you need to `return View();` in your Post method.